# using Terminal command by clicking on a link in an email?

Tags: command-line, automation

Can I send someone an email with a link, that opens the Terminal and installs Wine on Ubuntu 16.04?

I did it on my own system with the commands below, but I'd like to make it simple for someone...

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: I very much hope that this is not possible ...    using copy-paste is not an option ?

Comment: You also can send it as an attachment but the recipient has to a) make the file executable or b) explicitly run it in shell (e.g. `sh <file>`).

Comment: @KBen, please don't be so angry. I couldn't see any script or how do you execute it. Only bunch of commands. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and in first place some articles as: [Getting started with bash scripting](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-shell-scripting-lessons/). Then [edit] and elaborate your question.